# Rails multiple joins return empty set. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm having problems wrapping my head around using .joins on multiple associations. This is my model setup:

```
class Article
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :article
end

class Tag
  belongs_to :article
end
```

I'm trying to find all articles with a comment that has a specific comment body OR a tag with a specific tag text. This is my query:

```
Article.joins(:tags, :comments).where("(\"tags\".\"tag\" = 'awesome') OR (\"comments\".\"body\" = 'hello')
```

It's always returning an empty result. The weirdest thing is that this will work:

```
Article.joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:tag => "awesome:})
```

But when I add the other joins symbol, nothing is returned:

`Article.joins([:tags, :comments]).where(:tags => {:tag => "awesome"})`

Does this make any sense? Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: is it the case that some of the tagged articles may have no comments (or conversely that some of the commented articles may have no tags)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`joins` with an array or symbol argument in Rails always does an [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in sql, even when joining multiple tables.

So when you have no articles with both tags and comments ( or those articles that do have both tags and comments do not match your condition ), you will receive an empty result because you only match these conditions to the cross-section of articles having both comments *and* tags.

To get really all articles with tags and comments, do a `LEFT JOIN` by yourself

```
Article.joins("LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.article_id = articles.id 
               LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id")
```

And then apply your condition.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed!